# Git commit only for me

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, commit, git-commit

I was wondering, is there an option in git for me to commit my changes so I can continue working on my other PC/laptop without anyone else being able to pull?

Example, I'm working on a feature in one of the branches (notice that I don't want to create a new branch), on my desktop pc and since I didn't finish it and I have to go some place for a couple of days, I want to continue working on my laptop, but I don't want others to be able to pull since it isn't finished it can cause some unwanted behaviour.

So basically, to commit only for myself and later when I finish I can push to everyone else on the project.

Comment: Why haven't you created a branch? This is the typical signal to say "work in progress".

Comment: Because I don't want to create a new branch every time I want to switch from my pc to my laptop. I understand the point of branching, I was just wondering if there is a feature like I explained in the question. @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: The only way for you to share your commits **only** with yourself across multiple computers is to either set up your own private repository on github or somewhere else, and then push/pull to that, or to push/pull between your computers directly.

Comment: And note that I'm not advocating creating a branch just for switching between your computers, I'm advocating creating a branch when you start working on something where you will have multiple commits before you're finished, that way you can still push your branch to the central github repository without fear of anyone pulling by mistake.

Comment: Maybe that push/pull between computers is exactly what I need, could you please explain it in an answer. Better explanation of my problem is that the feature was already built and pushed and is working, I had to make some changes to it, but I have no time to test it on the machine I'm working on currently, so that's why I want to switch it between computers so I can test it later on then push it. @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: i would ask first... why do you need hide it?

Comment: Mostly since everyone else is using one version of the feature, and I don't want to mess something up for everyone until it's fully built and tested. I don't want to create a new branch for one/two commits. @MarceloFilho

Comment: But do know that you're asking how *not* use the feature that is actually *meant* to handle this particular type of thing. Any hint or guide or information you will get will likely include "why can't you simply create a branch" since that is the tool meant for this type of thing.

Comment: @Imaginaroom, **do** create a branch for one/two commits, **do push** to it, and after you merge it, **do delete it in the end** (`git push origin :name` or `git push -d origin name`). Important point of git branching model is that they are disposable. Never ever think twice about creating a branch in git!

Comment: In any case, to push/pull between your computers they will need disk access between each other, so you could simply do `git remote add othercomputer \\othercomputer\share\repo` or similar.

Comment: Also, you might at some point think "Hey, I can just use my Dropbox account for this" (and insert your favorite automagic-sync-folder-across-computers type of tool here), but **no**. **DO NOT USE DROPBOX TO SYNC DVCS REPOSITORIES!**. It will fail, and when it does, it will fail horribly.

Comment: The cost of a branch is a file on disk that is 41 bytes in size, nothing more, branches are super-cheap in git, so you shouldn't worry about the branch. Delete it when you're done with it and use git the way it is meant to be used.

Comment: such an effort for nothing i would say... use your pendrive then: create a local branch, copy everything into your pendrive, transport, plug back and make your changes from the pendrive... hehehe, was a joke but is totally pointless this need once as said before, git was made to you be able to branch and test faster! good luck... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I don't want others to be able to pull since it isn't finished it can cause some unwanted behaviour.

The project is otherwise public, isn't it? So the commits will be visible anyway when you eventually publish next version, won't they? So they can't contain anything illegal or otherwise problematic, can they? The only thing they can is be broken state…

Therefore, if somebody wants to shoot themselves in the foot by explicitly pulling code from a branch called `for-test` or `experiment`, it's their problem, not yours.

Therefore, **do push to a branch**. Name it `test` (or `for-test` or `experiment` or something like that, but *nothing fancy, please*). And I mean those suggestions very literally; the branches will only exist until you test on the other machine!

Pushing to such branch is trivial:

```
git push origin HEAD:test
```

Then on the other machine, you just pull it:

```
git pull origin test
```

and test it and fix it. And when you are done and merge it to the actual target, you just **delete the test branch again**:

```
git branch -d test
```

gets rid of the local branch, and

```
git push -d origin test
```

gets rid of the one on github.

Yes, you can also set up remote for direct push from one computer to the other. But that requires to have them both running and on the same network and have ssh connection or something. And then you'll want to ask somebody else to also test it and you'll need the `test` branch anyway.

So do make a `test` branch; branches are cheap.

This is a big difference compared to traditional centralized version control systems where commits belonged to branches. There you had to think carefully before creating one, because they were there to stay forever. But in distributed systems branches are just labels for revisions that can be easily added to already existing revisions and easily deleted when they are no longer needed. Once you get used to it, you'll find branches are much more useful in git and other distributed systems then they used to be in the older systems.

Comment: how can it be a answer? hehehe

Comment: @MarceloFilho, because the asker fortunately explains why they want to do something and the solution they were looking at is not the most appropriate one. It is quite common that question of the form “how do I use X to do Y” has answer of the form “use Z instead” and fortunately the “Y” was included here, so corresponding “Z” could be provided. Yes, I could explain direct push and stuff, but that would support irrational fear of creating temporary branches, which are a good thing and not something to be feared.

Comment: @MarceloFilho, no, it wouldn't. It is an answer—to the actual problem—and it is too long for a comment anyway.